# Reference request: "If $a$ and $m$ are coprime then there must exist $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod m$"

Tags: reference-request, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I state in a project that

> "If $a$ and $m$ are coprime then there must exist $k \in \mathbb{N}$
>   such that $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod m$."

I am fairly confident that this is true, but was hoping that someone could help me to find a reference to verify this statement?

Comment: We know even better. Euler's (totient) theorem tells us that $k = \phi(m)$ does the job, where $\phi$ is the totient function.  EDIT : Wikipedia is good enough. It even gives proofs.

Comment: This is known as *Euler's theorem* or the *Fermat-Euler theorem*.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is known as 'Euler's theorem' and is a generalizations of 'Fermat's little theorem', see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem#Generalizations). The proof should be in any beginner's book on Number Theory.

*Sketch:* If $\rm{gcd}(a,m)=1$, then $a \in G:=(\mathbb{Z} \setminus n \mathbb{Z})^*$:  One can just use Euclid's algorithm in order to find $ax+bm =1$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. This implies $ax \equiv 1 \ \rm{mod} \, m$. Since $G$ is finite, $\{a^k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a finite group, i.e. there exists a smallest natural number $k>0$ with $a^k =1$. Moreover, $k$ divides $|G| = \varphi(n)$. $k>0$ is maybe smaller than $\varphi(n)$, but we always have $a^{\varphi(n)} =1$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, $a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ is Euler's Theorem. The mere fact that there is $k > 0$ such that $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ is, as you note, just a consequence of the fact that ${\mathbb Z}_m^*$ is a finite group which contains (the residue class of) $a$.